# Determine width based on percentage using only CSS

Tags: html, css

I have three columns (divs floating left), each with a width of 30% plus 3% padding. Each column contains an image that is 100px wide. Next to each image, I want to put a title/description next to that, which will take up the rest of the space in that column.

I know you can't do math in CSS, so we couldn't just do something like `width: 33% - 100px;` (would be awesome if you could). I could determine it with JavaScript, but I'm trying to avoid using JS for this task, if possible. I would rather see if anyone can come up with a better design where I wouldn't have to do that.

See my example on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7prc/).

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="column3 item" style="border-right:1px dotted #CCC;">
    <img src="images/items/item1.jpg" />
    <div>
        <b>Item 1</b>
        <p>Some kind of description about the item goes here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column3 item" style="border-right:1px dotted #CCC;">
    <img src="images/items/item2.jpg" />
    <div>
        <b>Item 2</b>
        <p>Some kind of description about the item goes here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column3 item clearfix">
    <img src="images/items/item3.jpg" />
    <div>
        <b>Item 3</b>
        <p>Some kind of description about the item goes here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
.column3 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0 1.5%;
}

.column3 > div {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.column3 > div > p {
    display: inline-block;
}

.item img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

So I need to figure out how to set the width of the inner div so that it will take up the rest of the space. I know I can do this with JS, but I would really prefer a CSS solution so that when the user resizes the page, it automatically adjusts that width (without having to call a JS `resize` event listener) and then all of my styling will be kept in one place, reducing the complexity.

None of this code is set in stone, so if you can suggest a better HTML/CSS structure, that would be a perfectly acceptable solution.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: I'm just guessing, but maybe a CSS 'holy grail' would be helpful? http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail (it's also backwards compatible)

Comment: @Mash: I didn't know about that. It looks pretty sweet, but can't really rely on it of it only works with IE9+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

### Demo

CSS:

```
.column3 {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100px;
    position:relative;
    padding: 0 1.5%;
}
.column3 > div {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0ff;
    margin-left:100px;
    padding-left:-100px;
}
.column3 > div > p {
    display: inline-block;
}
.item img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
/* clearfix */
 .clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.clearfix {
    zoom: 1;
    /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
/* END clearfix */
```

HTML:

```
<div class="column3 item" style="border-right:1px dotted #CCC;">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
    <div> <b>Item 1</b>
        <p>Some kind of description about the item goes here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column3 item" style="border-right:1px dotted #CCC;">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
    <div> <b>Item 2</b>
        <p>Some kind of description about the item goes here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="column3 item clearfix">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" />
    <div> <b>Item 3</b>
        <p>Some kind of description about the item goes here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry it took me so long to respond...was away for the weekend. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float on the inner `div` and make the margin large enough for it to fit alongside the image:

```
.column3 > div {
    margin-left: 105px;
}
```

The only downside of this is that if the description is longer than the height of the image, it won't flow across under the image, but will remain over to the side. You could achieve that by removing the margin altogether and instead making the `p` `display: inline`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do math with CSS3.

```
width: calc(100% - 30% - 3%); /* width 100% minus column width, minus padding */
```

or

```
width: calc(100% - 100px); /* width 100% minus image width */
```

Of course, use vendor prefixes:

```
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 30% - 3%); /* width 100% minus column width, minus padding */
width: -moz-calc(100% - 30% - 3%); /* width 100% minus column width, minus padding */
width: -o-calc(100% - 30% - 3%); /* width 100% minus column width, minus padding */
width: -ms-calc(100% - 30% - 3%); /* width 100% minus column width, minus padding */
width: calc(100% - 30% - 3%); /* width 100% minus column width, minus padding */
```

You can multiply, divide, whatever you need to do. David Walsh gives a few more examples: http://davidwalsh.name/css-calc . You can also see which browsers support it specifically: http://caniuse.com/calc . Opera is the only modern browser without support for it, however it's on it's way...

Comment: Unfortunately, my implementation will need to support older browsers as well. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You can fix that though with modernizr. Makes CSS3 compatible in all browsers.